# Cann't install Ubuntu 18.04 on Acer Aspire 4720Z

Tags: 18.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Acer Aspire 4720Z but failed. My installaition stuck in the very beginning on bootlogo. I updated BIOS on latest version form Acer site.
Previously I successfully instaled Ubuntu 16.04 in that laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 is a 64bit OS and does not support 32bit computers like Acer aspier 4720Z. Ubuntu MATE 18.04 still works on 32bit computers. You can download it at [ubuntu-mate.org](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/)